# is it possible to embed a fractal inside another fractal

Tags: geometry, fractals, pattern-recognition, cellular-automata

I have been looking at one-dimensional (1D) cellular automata (CAs) which generate two-dimensional (2D) fractal patterns. Among the 256 1D elementary CAs, I tried to list down the fractal generating ones by looking at pictures here https://www.wolframscience.com/nks/p54--more-cellular-automata/

I was wondering if it is possible to list down both elementary and non-elementary CAs which generate fractals? The elementary CAs that generate fractals can be listed down by checking the 256 patterns. But it also seems there is a formal result i.e. the elementary CAs which can be represented by a linear recursive relation for the CA states are the ones that generate fractals. I wonder if this is generalized to non-elementary CAs.

My main question is related to this and is simple to state: is there a fractal which can be embedded inside another fractal? Note that these two fractals do not have to be generated by elementary CAs. Any reference that goes into this will be helpful. By embedding, I mean that all the 1 automata states of one fractal coincide with a subset of the 1 automata states of the other fractal.

Comment: Every fractal can be embedded in a strictly larger fractal, assuming that you define a fractal as a closed planar set of noninteger Hausdorff dimension.

Comment: @MoisheKohan can you please explain more. Please look at my question again. I have defined what I meant by embedding. Considering that, can you embed Sierpinski fractal inside Fibonacci fractal for example? The linear update rule for the former is $s_{i,t+1}=s_{i,t}+s_{i+1,t}$ and for the latter is $s_{i,t+1}=s_{i-1,t}+s_{i,t}+s_{i+1,t}$.

Comment: For CA, you might be interested in the notion of universality (and intrinsic universality). Basically, a CA is intrinsically universal if it can simulate (in a precise sense) any other CA. A survey is Ollinger's paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/0906.3213.pdf, where precise definitions are given, and references that Banks proved that there exists a 1D CA which is intrinsically universal.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "can be placed on top."

Comment: All the 1 automata states have to coincide with a subset of the 1 automata states of the underlying fractal

Comment: In the definition of a fractal is self similar.